# Iterate over just some elements of a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I've got a Hash that looks like this:

```
card = {
  name: "Mrs.Jones",
  number: "4242 4242 4242 4242",
  exp_month: "12",
  exp_year: "2014",
  address: "90210 Beverly Hills",
  added: "2014-11-09 09:14:23"
}
```

I'd like to iterate over just the `number`,`exp_month` and `exp_year` fields and update them. What's the most Ruby-like way of doing that?

This is what my code looks like at present:

```
card.each do |key,value|
  card[key] = encrypt(value) # Only apply to number, exp_month and exp_year
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it the following way:

```
ENCRYPTED_FIELDS = [:number, :exp_month, :exp_year]

card.each do |key,value|
  card[key] = encrypt(value) if ENCRYPTED_FIELDS.include?(key)
end
```

But a better option would be to make a class for CreditCardDetails and define the setters to encrypt the data:

```
class CreditCardDetails
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |k, v|
      self.send("#{k}=", v)
    end
  end

  #example for not encrypted field
  def name=(value)
    @name = value
  end 

  #example for encrypted field
  def number=(value)
    @number = encrypted(value)
  end
end
```

Comment: Gosh I love your approach on that second answer.

Comment: It should definitely be an object ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since you already know which keys you'd like to encrypt, you can iterate over the wanted key names, instead of the hash:

```
ENCRYPTED_FIELDS = [:number, :exp_month, :exp_year]

ENCRYPTED_FIELDS.each do |key|
  card[key] = encrypt(card[key])
end
```

Comment: Aha, that works too! I suppose another option would be to use `slice` and pass in the fields: `card.slice(:number, :exp_month, :exp_year).each do |k,v| ...`. Thanks Uri!

Comment: @FloatingRock Or `card.slice(*ENCRYPTED_FIELDS)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways to do it. I've replaced the method `encrypt` with `size`, for purposes of illustration. They both use the form of [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block. The second approach does not use keys. Instead, it processes the value if the value is all digits (and spaces). I included that mainly to illustrate what you might do in other applications.

**#1**

```
card.merge(card) do |k,_,v|
  case k
  when :number, :exp_month, :exp_year
    v.size
  else
    v
  end
end
  #=> {:name=>"Mrs.Jones", :number=>19, :exp_month=>2, :exp_year=>4,
  #    :address=>"90210 Beverly Hills", :added=>"2014-11-09 09:14:23"}
```

**#2**

```
card.merge(card) { |*_,v| v[/^[\s\d]+$/] ? v.size : v }
  #=> {:name=>"Mrs.Jones", :number=>19, :exp_month=>2, :exp_year=>4,
  #    :address=>"90210 Beverly Hills", :added=>"2014-11-09 09:14:23"}
```

If you want to mutate `card`, use [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (a.k.a. `merge!`) rather than `merge`:

**#1a**

```
card.update(card) do |k,_,v|
  case k
  when :number, :exp_month, :exp_year
    v.size
  else
    v
  end
end
  #=> {:name=>"Mrs.Jones", :number=>19, :exp_month=>2, :exp_year=>4,
  #    :address=>"90210 Beverly Hills", :added=>"2014-11-09 09:14:23"}

card
  #=> {:name=>"Mrs.Jones", :number=>19, :exp_month=>2, :exp_year=>4,
  #    :address=>"90210 Beverly Hills", :added=>"2014-11-09 09:14:23"}
```

Comment: Thanks Cary. Why does `card.update` in #1a return `|k,_,v|` and what does the `_` do?

Comment: If you check the docs for `merge` and `update` you will see that both pass an array of three values into the block. If we assign a block variable for each of the three values, we would have `|k,ov,v|`. (Please see the docs for details.) In #1 and #1a I  use only `k` and `v`, so I chosen to replace `ov` with a "placeholder" `_`, merely too draw attention to the fact that I'm not using it. (I could also write `|k,_ov,v|`, but you rarely see that.) In #2 I use only the block variable `v`, so I can write `|_,_,v|`, or equivalently, `|*_,v|`.